# PostgreSQL: truncate hour/min/second from a timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select

I am using the following query to change all date to the Monday of the corresponding week:

```
select  date_trunc('week', join_date) as join_wk from my_table
```

This query converts `2017-08-23 11:30:02` to `2017-08-21 00:00:00`

I am wondering if it is possible to remove the `hour/min/second`from the output `2017-08-21 00:00:00`? i.e. make the output in the format of `2017-08-21`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date_trunc` returns a `timestamp`. You could cast it to a `date` to lose the time part of it:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', join_date)::DATE AS join_wk FROM my_table
-- Here ----------------------------^
```